# remove/ignore TODO keyword in VS2012 Task List

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tasklist

I want the task list to show only my TODO comments, but I'm using some external libraries which I wish to include as projects in my solutions. Those external projects have many TODO comments in them.

I tried adding new keywords, and deleting or changing the priority of the TODO keyword - but it's simply not letting me.

Do you know of any solution/hack?

Comment: Did you find a way to delete the TODO kayword?